# how to retrieve date in computed field

Tags: 7, datetime, entities

How to retrieve date from a date field and store it in computed field? I have tried this code:

```
$start_date = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_start_date')));
$entity_field[1]['value'] = $start_date;
```

But it displays 'datetime'. I want to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're indiscriminately popping values off of the array returned from `field_get_items`, without checking to see which index you actually need. I haven't tested this but I think you'll have better luck with code like this:

```
$items = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_start_date');

// Use array_shift if you want the FIRST field item
$item = array_shift($items);
// OR
// Use array_pop if you want the LAST field item
$item = array_pop($items);

// Get the date value of the field
$start_date = $item['value'];

// Use start date
$entity_field[1]['value'] = $start_date;
```